# How to Send email with the Stored Procedure result

Tags: sendmail, alert

I'm wondering if there is a way to have SQL Mail automatically send an email with an attachment when a 
certain query is complete. Say I want to run a query, and when it's finished, send the results as well as an
attachment as a report via SQL Mail. Is this possible, and if so, does anyone have any idea where I can find
information on how to do this?

Answer (score 0):

Which database are you using?  I know that MySQL can have compiled user defined functions (UDF) loaded into it to perform custom actions.  On Oracle, you can load jar files which can be called using triggers.  On MS SqlServer, you can load a .net binary which can be called from triggers.  It has full access to the .net framework which would include mail.

**update**
On SqlServer 2005 you can load a .net assembly into the database.  Here is a simple tutorial [link](http://www.sqldbatips.com/showarticle.asp?ID=22).  What it enables you to do is to call your .net code (say a .dll) and that code will be executed by the database.  In the example it only calls "hello world" at the database console, but you could change your hello world program to write to a file or send out an email.  In your case you would want to create a routine which sends out emails.  In the database you can create a trigger which listens to a table.  When you finish your query, it can insert into that table firing the trigger.  The trigger will then call your .net assembly and send the email out.  You can write your function to take in input arguments which can be results you mentioned or anything else.

Comment: @Prasanna see my post for some additional info about SqlServer 2005